# sed linux command unable to insert line

Tags: regex, linux, sed

How can I make this regular expression work  correctly. Is adding the line

```
LOGIN_SERVICE: '"https://dev-login-o365.grey.com/gp_loginservice/"',
```

in the file `env.js`  I'm using the regular expresion:

```
sed -i '5i LOGIN_SERVICE: '"https://login.xxxx.com/server/"',' ./env.js
```

But is adding the value without the quotes and 3 spaces more to the left like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use different quoting:

```
sed -i "5i LOGIN_SERVICE: '\"https://login.xxxx.com/server/\"'," env.js
```

Or as the helpful comments below suggest, wrap `sed` command in single quote:

```
sed '5i LOGIN_SERVICE: '\''"https://login.xxxx.com/server/"'\'',' env.js
```

Comment: Alternatively, `'5i LOGIN_SERVICE: '\''"https://login.xxxx.com/server/"'\'','` - this is useful for programmatic quoting, since it's just `s.replace("'", "'\\''")`

Comment: Don't use double quotes around scripts as then you're exposing the whole text to the shell for interpretation before sed even sees it so you'll get a surprise if/when your text contains characters the shell will act on (e.g. $). Just do `sed -i '5i LOGIN_SERVICE: '\''"https://login.xxxx.com/server/"'\'',' ./env.js` instead like @o11c suggested.

Comment: Thanks, That's fair point Ed and @o11c